# shell script not executing without errors

Tags: linux, cygwin, sh, pscp

I wrote a shell script to copy a file from Windows directory to a remote Linux machine. I'm using cygwin to run the script. The script gets executed without any error. I'm using `pscp` to copy files, but the file is not being copied. Putty is installed & environment variable is set.

Without putting in `.sh` file, the `pscp` command copies the files.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
logFile=/cygdrive/e/Automated/Po_transfer/po_filesfileTransfer.log 
 d=`date +%d-%m-%Y`
 t=$(date +"%T")
cd /cygdrive/e/Automated/Po_transfer/
FileName=`ls -tr|grep PO*_BV.csv >> $logFile`
pscp -pw abcd $FileName user@xxx.yy.zz.qq:/home/ckp/po
if [ $? = 0 ];
then
echo "$d  $t  $FileName transferred to Asics Factory successfully" >> $logFile
fi
```

The script has to copy the files to destination directory on Linux machine, but console shows:

```
./PO_Transfer.sh
PuTTY Secure Copy client
Release 0.70
Usage: pscp [options] [user@]host:source target
       pscp [options] source [source...] [user@]host:target
       pscp [options] -ls [user@]host:filespec
```

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting?  And if you're using cygwin, why bother with `pscp` instead of the **native** `scp` with keys?

Comment: on Window 16, im using the similar type of script, there the scripts works fine.

Comment: That doesn't help; I have no idea what "window 16" is. And the formatting is still suboptimal. Use code tags.

Comment: on Windows 16 OS , the PSCP command working fine.

Comment: @tink , check to code now and please let me know why the script does not copy files to remote linux machine, whereas command `pscp -pw abcd $FileName user@xxx.yy.zz.qq:/home/ckp/po` able to copy files when ran on cgywin

Comment: Impossible to know for sure, but given that `pscp` spits out a usage message I'll hazard the guess that you have files with spaces or other "odd" characters in the name that confuse the shell.  Try quoting the variable.

Comment: Make sure your script file is using LF only for line endings, not CRLF. Use the `dos2unix` or `d2u` or you text editor to fix the line endings. Use `cat -A PO_Transfer.sh` to check the line endings in your script file.

Comment: Hi @DougHenderson , the Script is using LF. But Dont know whats causing the issue.

Comment: If the `pscp` command is a windows program, you will need to use `cygpath` to convert Unix style filenames to Windows style. E.g. `$( cygpath -w $FileName )`

Comment: Just a second there - what is the value of $FileName. Is it blank? Do you need a `| tee` after the grep?

Comment: Hi @DougHenderson , the script fixed